# Oracle PLSQL Dependency chain (Invalid objects)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I was going through an article - "Procedure vs Package" - where I found this statement:

> break the dependency chain (no cascading invalidations when you
>   install a new package body -- if you have procedures that call
>   procedures -- compiling one will invalidate your database)

I tried it but don't see any invalid objects. Below is the code I am using on Oracle 12C.

```
create or replace procedure B 
as 
begin 
null; 
End; 

create or replace procedure A 
as 
begin 
B; 
end; 

alter procedure B compile;

select object_type, object_name, status 
from user_objects 
Where Status = 'INVALID' 
order by object_type, object_name
```

Am I missing something or things have changed in Oracle 12c?

Comment: Might be helpful (or at least interesting) to include a link to the article. [This](http://ora-plsql.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/procedures-functions-packages-interview.html), perhaps? Or [this](http://ora-plsql.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/procedures-functions-packages-interview.html) - which links to [an old Ask Tom post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:1669015774188148::::P11_QUESTION_ID:286816015990), from 2000, when that was a more reasonable comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to [finer grained dependencies from 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO07519). Your example invalidates A in 10g, but not in 11g. So no, it changed in 11g, not 12c...

The documentation on [invalidation of dependent objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/dependencies.htm#CNCPT1862) says:

> Direct dependents are invalidated only by changes to the referenced object that affect them (changes to the signature of the referenced object).

In 11g procedure A isn't invalidated if you recompile it with `alter`, as you did, or if you repeat the whole `create or replace` statement:

```
alter procedure B compile;

select ...

no rows selected

create or replace procedure B
as 
begin 
null;
end; 
/

select ...

no rows selected
```

But it will still be invalidated if the procedure signature changes - if you add a parameter argument:

```
create or replace procedure B (x number)
as 
begin 
null;
End; 
/

select object_type, object_name, status 
from user_objects 
Where Status = 'INVALID' 
and object_name in ('A','B')
order by object_type, object_name;

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME          STATUS 
------------------- -------------------- -------
PROCEDURE           A                    INVALID
```

Comment: I see this behavior is same for procedure and package. If we change the signature of referenced object, both proc and package becomes invalid. Is there any difference between procedure and package in terms of handling the changes in referenced object?

Comment: Not any more, as far as I'm aware. Both will also be invalidated by, say, a change to a tablle they refer too. And both will automatically be recompiled the next time they are called - which may fail depeneding on what changed and how it is used.